# Laravel 5.2 trans() gives me htmlentity encoded strings instead of characters

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm making English-Spanish website so depending the language I have to give the user different strings. To do it I'm using Laravel's trans() function.

The problem is that in Blade the trans() outputs html entity encoded characters.

So for example when I put `{{ trans('messages.title') }}` which points to the string

`'title' => 'Título'` in the lang file, instead of `Título` I have `T&iacute;tulo`.

But if I just have the string (or character) put directly in the file it is shown normally.

Is this normal in Laravel 5.2 that trans() function outputs htmlentity encoded string instead of normal UTF8 character?
If not any idea what I'm doing wrong?
If yes is it possible to output normal characters instead?

Comment: Try with {!! trans('messages.title') !!}

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that when I use `@lang()` instead of `{{ trans() }}` it gives me the character.
So it looks like this is how it works.

But if there is anybody who knows and can confirm that this behavior is intentional and correct, that would be great.